# Why does my simple typescript function expect a jQueryEventObject parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have the following code:

```
function submitSuccessAccess() {
    $(".accessLink")
        .attr("data-disabled", "no");
    window.location.reload();
}
```

I am trying to call this function like this:

```
submitSuccessAccess();
```

However I get a red underline under submitSuccessAccess saying: supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. Seems like the submitSuccessAccess is expecting:

```
(eventObject: JQueryEventObject) => any
```

I found a temporary solution. I define and use as follows:

```
function submitSuccessAccess(any) {
    $(".accessLink")
        .attr("data-disabled", "no");
    window.location.reload();
}
submitSuccessAccess(null);
```

Am I the only one to experience anything like this?

Answer (score 2):

Because of a bug in typescript.

Try specifiying the return type of your function to change the function definition with the definition found in jQuery.d.ts of:

```
jqueryevent(handler: (eventObject: JQueryEventObject) => any): JQuery;
```

Where jqueryevent is like click,bind, ect.

Your definition could be:

```
function submitSuccessAccess():void {
    $(".accessLink")
        .attr("data-disabled", "no");
    window.location.reload();
}
```

And probably your calling context was something like this:

```
$(selector).click(function() {
    submitSuccessAccess();
});
```

Which was initialized by somthing like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initSubmitAccessFunction();
})
```

Comment: @Nicktar Hopefully my edit has improved the formatting a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The actual code for your function could be:

```
function submitSuccessAccess(eventObject: JQueryEventObject) {
    $(".accessLink")
        .attr("data-disabled", "no");
    window.location.reload();
}
```

If you don't like supplying the parameter you might change the relevant line in the jquery.d.ts file

```
(eventObject: JQueryEventObject) => any
```

to

```
(eventObject?: JQueryEventObject) => any
```

which it should probably have been like this in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your help but can you explain to me. Why would it default to being (eventObject: JQueryEventObject)?  All I want to do is to call one function with no parameters but it seems like the JQueryEventObject is being passed or expected.